# PHP 5.3 FTP JSON file upload using ftp_put Not uploading

Tags: php, json, file-upload, ftp, binaryfiles

I have a json file where I want to upload it to an ftp account on different server.
I have followed all the code of this function but still I get failed Upload!
here is my code:

```
$con        = ftp_connect('ftp.target-server.com');
$login      = ftp_login($con, 'usr', 'pa55');
if (!$con || !$login) {
    die('Connection attempt failed!');
}
$destination    = 'my-target-file.json';
$source         = 'my-source-file.json';
ftp_pasv($con, true) or die("Unable switch to passive mode"); //I have tried this option to force passive mode
$upload       = ftp_put($con, $destination, $source, FTP_BINARY); //options: FTP_BINARY|FTP_ASCII and I have tried both
if (!$upload){
    echo 'Upload failed!<br><br><br>';
}else{
    echo "DONE!";
}
ftp_close($con);
```

I always get failure although everything seems OK.
N.B.

- I have tried the access through filezilla ftp client and I managed to
  upload the file manually to target destination.
- The source server is using older PHP 5.3 but looks fine regarding the ftp_put function.
- Also I have tried my-target-file.txt instead of .json and also failed upload.
- I have tried couple of different shared hosting serveres as target server but no luck.
- I will be grateful if someone can advise!
- I have checked the last error using error_get_last(); and got:Array ( [type] => 2 [message] => ftp_put(): Type set to I [file] => /hermes/......../public/ftp.php [line] => 9 ). I can upload files normally through FTP client filezilla to the target server with the same credentials I am usingbut I can not with ftp_put() as it is not working

Comment: Does enabling error reporting (if you haven't already) show anything? http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: You're uploading what is an ascii file, why binary? Far as I know, JSON files are text, unless there's something I don't know.

Comment: I have tried error_reporting(E_ALL); at the begining of the code but gives nothing!

Comment: I receive only the error I am echoing "Upload failed!"

Comment: I have tried both FTP_BINARY and FTP_ASCII but no luck. I have to use FTP_BINARY as this is the instruction of the target server admin for the ftp account they gave me!

Comment: What about adding `error_get_last()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php?

Comment: this is what I get:
`Array ( [type] => 2 [message] => ftp_put(): Type set to I [file] => /hermes/......../public/ftp.php [line] => 9 )`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184364/discussion-between-willkoz-and-funk-forty-niner).

Comment: Do not even try without `ftp_pasv`. What error do you get with `error_get_last` from `ftp_put`, when using `ftp_pasv`? Did you check what `ftp_pasv` returns? Can you upload a file using any FTP client running on the same machine as your PHP code/webserver?

Comment: Please, edit your question, do not try to post important information in comments.

Comment: I've asked you to edit your question. Do not post important information in comments. Edit your question! + You didn't confirm if you run FileZilla on the same machine as your PHP code.

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice the remark but I have deleted the comment and edited the question with the same info. I ran the FileZilla from my computer to send local file to the remote server (server I do not administer but I have ftp credentials for) but the ftp_put function are run from a shared hosting of mine to try to send similar file to the remote server using same ftp_credentials but not sending!

Comment: So you have no way to test, if you even have a network connectivity with the FTP server from the webserver? Did you ask your hosting provider, if they even allow outgoing FTP connections? Anyway, please include FileZilla log file.

Comment: thanks, I will check with the hosting server if they allow outgoing ftp connections as this is a probable cause.